# logcat reading very slow, never ends

Tags: android, logging, logcat, android-logcat

I am developing an product running on Android 2.3 on custom embedded hardware.

The applications running write logs very frequently to the logcat.

I want the logs in a file for which I tried :

```
logcat -f /tmp/comm-diag/androidLog -d -v time
```

and also

```
logcat -d -v time > /tmp/comm-diag/androidLog
```

But the logcat commands never exits, the memory consumption keeps on increasing (top command) and after around 15-20 mins the board reboots.

If I reduce the number/frequency of logs from the application, the logcat commands runs and exits successfully.

Does that mean that the logcat write speed is more than logcat read speed ? What is the solution to this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the only solution to this problem at the moment is abruptly disconnecting the device while debugging is on. After doing so, logcat will display `"device not found"`. Logcat will then read logs from the last "device not found" event instead of many hours in past.